# i am trying to design Laravel 8 login page but i am not able to find login page

Tags: php, laravel, inertiajs, laravel-jetstream

I am trying to design Laravel 8 login page but not found where is it.
I am use Laravel 8 and AUTH package is " Jetstream inertia "

below page are customize but not changes anything

resources\views\auth\login.blade.php
resources\js\Pages\Auth\Login.vue

Comment: Make sure you install the npm dependencies and run `npm run dev` or `npm run watch` to compile your .vue files.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jetstream with the Inertia stack, `resources\views\auth\login.blade.php` is definitely the file you need to be editing to change the login page.

Further to that, the lyout page you want to edit for changes is `guest.blade.php found here:` resources\views\layouts\guest.blade.php`.

**guest.blade.php**

```
<body class="bodygradient">
    <div class="font-sans text-gray-900 antialiased">
        {{ $slot }} //login.blade.php is rendered right here
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

If your changes are not reflected you likely have a browser caching issue.